# Backobone how can i fetch data and console it

Tags: backbone.js

I am very new to use backone.js, i am trying to fetch json data from model and consoling it, but nothing i am getting...

anyone advice me the correct way to console and see the data using while i parse my response in model..

code :

```
(function($){   

var list = {};

list.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    name:'need the name'
  },
  urlRoot : 'data/names.json',
  parse:function(response){
    console.log(response);// i am not get any data..
    return response.results;
  }
});



list.view = Backbone.View.extend({

});

var newList = new list.model;
var newView = new list.view({model:newList});


})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `fetch` method.
You can do this inside model `initialize` method:

```
initialize : function() {
  this.fetch();
}
```

Or after creating model instance:

```
var newList = new list.model;
newList.fetch();
```

**EDIT:**
Fiddle:

```
var list = {};

list.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    name : 'need the name'
  },
  url : 'https://graph.facebook.com/4?fields=id,name',
  initialize : function(response) {
    this.fetch();
  },
  parse : function(response){
    console.log(response); // <- {"id":"4","name":"Mark Zuckerberg"}
    return response;
  }
});

list.view = Backbone.View.extend({});

var newList = new list.model;
var newView = new list.view({model:newList});
```

Comment: i made this correction but the response not consoling anything

Comment: can you fiddle the stuff. so it would easy to understand..?